# Custom Search Google показывает результаты в модальном окне

Tags: google-search

Использую на сайте CSE Google. Подключила стандартный вариант

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123:456"></script>
<div class="gcse-search">
```

По идее результат должен выводиться на странице ниже формы ввода запроса, но у меня почему-то он выводится в модальном окне

[image: результаты по запросу "Болт м8"]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно настроить в личном кабинете https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/
Изменение поисковой системы -> Внешний вид